# How to do module aliasing in NodeJS serverless framework

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, module-alias

take note: inside src folder

I want to achieve module aliasing name instead of using require("../../services"), require("../../models").

i want to achieve something like this: require("@services"), require("@models");

How to achieve this on serverless framework with node js without using webpack or babel

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add alias to your node.js project :

You need to do three things. Add a jsconfig.json file at te root of your project, add _moduleAliases option and the module-alias lib inside your package.json and finally import the lib at the very top of your index.js.

---

#### 1. Library installation

Run the following command to install the lib :

```bash
npm i --save module-alias
```

---

#### 2. Jsconfig.json

Add a jsconfig.json will help your IDE to detect that you are using aliases. Here is an example of jsconfig.json file :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "common/*"
      ],
      "@routes/*": [
        "common/routes/*"
      ],
      "@utils/*": [
        "common/utils/*"
      ],
      "@helper/*": [
        "common/helper/*"
      ],
      "@hooks/*": [
        "common/hooks/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "common/**/*"
  ]
}
```

---

#### 3. package.json

It is here that the magic happened. In your package.json file add the following lines.

> It is important to be synchronised with the jsconfig.json file in order to get fully working aliases. !

```json
  ...
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@": ".",
    "@routes": "common/routes",
    "@utils": "common/utils",
    "@hooks": "common/hooks",
    "@helper": "common/helper"
  },
  "depedencies": {
   ...
   "module-alias": "^2.2.2" #Latest current version
   ...
  },
  ...
```

---

#### 4. Index.js

At the very top of your index.js file add the following code :

```js
require('module-alias/register')
...
```

This normally should do the trick

If needed, see the documentation here :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias
- https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias

Comment: Hi @Hades, in serverless framework, we don't have index.js since it is invoking per lambda function (api endpoint). how to achieve without using index.js

Comment: Sorry for this late response. Can you provide a folder structure ?